# Will a thread pool automatically be shut down when changing Activities (should it even be used)?

Tags: java, android, frameworks, executorservice, android-lifecycle

I understand that it may not be the best option to use an `ExecuterService` (thread pools) in an `Android` application. I know how to use `AsyncTaskLoader` and `AsyncTask` as well as `services`. My question is more about better understanding the framework.

If I create a thread pool using the Executer framework in my Android application, and I don't declare the pool as static, will the threads still be available to the rest of the application when I leave the `Activity` it is created in? Will I have created "zombie threads" that aren't accessible but continue to use memory resources (memory leak).

I know that you need to shut down the service and this can be done in `onDestroy()`. I'm just curious if the pool is still reachable if it is created, not shutdown and also declared public. Thank you for you explanations in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thread pool is independent from activity, fragment lifecycle. So, yes it will run even after destroying activity.

Comment: but, my real question/curiosity is, can you still access it from another activity if it's public? Or, does it's variable need to be labeled static

Answer (score 0):

If a thread is still running, it continues to run even after onDestroy is called.  A thread cannot safely be cancelled by outside the thread itself, so nothing in the system will try. (Why not-  because its possible this will cause deadlock.  The system doesn't know what conditions a thread may be waiting for or locks it may be holding, or resources it may have claimed that will block other threads).

If all threads are finished, then shutting down the executorservice will kill all the threads.

As an aside-  your comments in the first paragraph shows you may not fully be aware of all the ins and outs of various asynchronous technologies available.  The reason you'd use thread pools and async tasks are very different, and a Service has nothing to do with threading on Android.